# Checking if a forked child has exec'ed yet in perl

Tags: linux, perl, exec, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I've got the following design in a perl script:

```
my $child_pid = fork;
if( ! $child_pid ){
    # do some stuff...
    exec( $user_specified_command );
else{
   # wait for child to exit
   waitpid( $child_pid, 0 );
}
# Continue with the script
```

I'm interested in getting an alert in the parent when the child execs, so that I can get some details about `$user_specified_command` (specifically, to use `lsof` to find out if stdout is redirected to a regular file). The result would be something like this:

```
my $child_pid = fork;
if( ! $child_pid ){
    # do some stuff...
    exec( $user_specified_command );
else{
   # wait until the child exec's
   wait_child_exec();

   # do some stuff...

   # wait for child to exit
   waitpid( $child_pid, 0 );
}
# Continue with the script
```

I could loop and grep `ps` output until the name changes, but it seems like exec is a serious enough event that there's a better way.

Comment: Would it be easier if you swapped the roles of child and parent?  After all, the parent has the child's PID, and can send a signal on this basis.

Comment: If I expect "this" process to send a signal before the exec, is there a chance that the OS won't have processed the exec yet, and my perl stuff could happen prematurely?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.  I should have thought of that, but didn't.  So, on your advice, another thought occurs:  could you program a wrapper around `$user_specified_command`?  The wrapper would receive two command-line arguments:  first, it would receive the PID of "this" process so that it could send the needed signal; second, it would receive `$user_specified_command`, so that it knew which command it was wrapping.  If this fails to solve the timing problem, then my approach is bad.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general approach to this is to create a pipe in the parent which is inherited by the child, and have the parent block (or poll) the read end of the pipe.

Assuming the child has FD_CLOEXEC or, better, a suitable value of `$^F`, the child's call to `exec()` will close the pipe's write end and generate an EOF for the parent:

```
# Run a command in a child process, returning to the parent only after
# the child process has called exec'd or, failing that, terminated.
#
# WARNING - this code not rigorously tested
#
sub spawn_patiently {
  my ($rd, $wr);

  return unless pipe($rd, $wr);
  # XXX This assumes $^F is less than fileno($wr)
  #     In practice, you'd want it to be less than fileno($rd), too

  my $pid = fork();
  return unless defined $pid;

  if (! $pid) {
    exec @_;
    die "exec: $!";
  }

  # parent - wait for child to exec
  close($wr);
  read($rd, my $dummy, 1);

  1;
}
```